# What's wrong with this RewriteRule?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Here's my code in htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/user/\?user=(.*)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /user/%1? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^user/(.*)$ /user/?user=$1 [L]
```

What I want it to do is take the URL `/user/?user=username` and rewrite it to `/user/username`
What I have successfully rewrites it to `/user/username` but then it gives me a 500 error. If anyone could tell me why I would be very appreciative.

Thanks!

Edit:
The 500 error seems to be because it's creating a redirect loop with this rule. I'm not sure how to take just the last part and append it to the URL as a query string.

Comment: Look in the server's error logs to see what the cause of the 500 was.

Comment: I'm not able to see the error logs but I'm pretty sure that the user name isn't properly making it into the $1 variable in the second rule.

Comment: Nevermind, that can't be it because that wouldn't cause a 500 error. It must be a syntax error in the rule itself.

Comment: I think it's actually creating a redirect loop.

Answer (score 1):

Please change this line :

```
RewriteRule ^user/(.*)$ /user/?user=$1 [L]
```

with this :

```
RewriteRule ^user/[a-zA-Z]+$ /user/?user=$1 [L]
```

You should match only letters , otherwise the above condition `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/user/\?user=(.*)\s [NC]` doesn't make any sense with `(.*)$`

Comment: I did this but it just rewrote `/user/username` to `/user/?user=` and didn't pass the username.

Comment: but what you need id to change  /user/?user=username to  /user/username, am Iright?

Comment: I check the code it works fine for me , try to empty browser cache